# How to split a time series data by range of date in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, dplyr

I am a beginner in R, and working on a time series monthly data:

I have selected the following  data columns from my dataframe

```
df = select(data, Date, Location, Production,  Value)
```

There are 13 different locations, multiple production sectors and their values. Date range is from 2016-01-2020-09.

I want to split the data into two columns: before covid (2016-01 to 2020-01), and after covid (2020-02 to 2020-09).
How do I do this in R ? Is there a simple method ?

Comment: It would be helpful to post the output of dput(df) or head(df) so people have a better idea of what you data looks like.

Comment: I would just assign a new covid column and assign before covid as `FALSE` and after covid as `TRUE`. This could be done by `df[df$Date < as.Date("2020-02-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"), 'Covid'] <- FALSE` and repeat the process to set dates greater than or equal to february as true.

Comment: Please make sure your `dput` is complete and share it via text not as image. The `Label = c("2016-01", ......),` part is incomplete so we cannot copy it into our R system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert to date class first and then specify the range in which we want to divide the data.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
       mutate(Date = as.Date(paste0(Date, '-01')), 
              period = case_when(between(Date, as.Date('2016-01-01'), 
                                    as.Date('2020-01-01')) ~ 'Before covid', 
                                  between(Date, as.Date('2020-01-02'), 
                                    as.Date('2020-11-01')) ~ 'After covid'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much,    Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `period`. x cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double' ℹ Input `period` is `case_when(...)`.

Comment: Here is the first few rows  of dput(head(df)). :  structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2016-01-01", ....), class = "factor"), Location = structure(c(4L, ....),

Comment: @Albert Please add the dput to your question. It's getting cut off in the comments.

Comment: @Albert Can you check the updated answer. You had `Date` column as factor in your `dput` which is different from what you had shown in the image earlier.

Comment: Great, works! Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this. Here's a `tidy` solution. There are several similar ways to do this, but I think this is pretty straightforward to follow.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(PreCovid = ifelse(Date < as.Date("2020-02-01"), Value, NA), 
         PostCovid = ifelse(Date >= as.Date("2020-02-01"), Value, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the following error message:   Problem with `mutate()` input `PreCovid`.
x Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "<.Date") for "<"
ℹ Input `PreCovid` is `ifelse(...)`.Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "<.Date") for "<"Problem with `mutate()` input `PostCovid`.
x Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", ">=.Date") for ">="
ℹ Input `PostCovid` is `ifelse(...)`.Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", ">=.Date") for ">="